# LaTeX Error: File `isodate.sty' not found

Tags: errors, texworks, isodate

I just started to use LaTeX and I have the following error running the blank university template using TeXworks:

> ! LaTeX Error: File `isodate.sty' not found.
>
> Type X to quit or  to proceed,
> or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
>
> Enter file name:

I can run older templates without problems as long `\RequirePackage[english,ngerman,num]{isodate}` is not written in the `.cls` file.

Is there an error in the template or do I just miss something?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Note that you don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: This means, that you have not installed the isodate.sty. Try this for a dirty fix: create a the file `isodate.sty` where the .tex is you are trying to compile. Now open the file and copy the content of [this](http://frs.home.cern.ch/frs/Source/NL_MD_02.07.2011/isodate.sty) in there. Try to run your .tex again.

Comment: Sounds that you have not installed package `isodate` on your computer ... Use the package management system (depends on your used tex distribution) to download and install it.

Comment: I used the MiKTeX Package Manager to install isodate and substr. Everything works fine now. Thank you.

Comment: dnf install texlive-isodate